# How to place color into React state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a stateful component that changes div background color after clicking on it. I keep a boolean flag in state, and when it changes, the component recalculating its color and rerendering itself.

How can I get rid of this boolean flag, I want to keep the color itself in state, and when the state with color changes, the component will rerender itself.

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { flag: true };
}
changeColor(){this.setState({flag: !this.state.flag})};

render(){
var bgColor = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
return ( <div style={{backgroundColor: bgColor}} onClick={this.changeColor.bind(this)}>wonderful</div> );
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: So store the string in the state.  What don't you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this into `changeColor` function

```
var bgColor = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
```

then store `bgColor` inside state within same `changeColor` function, e.g.

```
this.setState({ color: bgColor });
```

e.g.

```
class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {color: null};
}

changeColor(){
    this.setState({
        color: 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + 
        (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + 
        (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')' })
    };
}

render(){
  return ( 
    <div style={{backgroundColor: this.state.color}} 
      onClick={this.changeColor.bind(this)}
    >
      wonderful
    </div>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make color a state variable, calculate the initial color using the color function on `componentDidMount`, and then recalculate on click.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.setColor = this.setColor.bind(this)
    this.state = { 
      color: null 
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.setColor()
  }

  setColor () {
    let newColor = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')'
    this.setState({color: newColor})
  }

  render () {
    return ( 
      <div style={{backgroundColor: this.state.color}} onClick={this.setColor}>
        wonderful
      </div> 
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='root' />
```